# Is there an Ubuntu alternative to mac OSX "Webcams" dashboard widget?

Tags: software-recommendation, webcam

While I was running OSX I enjoyed the [*Webcams* dashboard widget](https://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/webcams/webcams.html).

It consolidates a number of webcam images from Internet webcams into a kind of thumbnail overview, and you can click one of these to get a larger image. You configure it by giving the URLs to the respective webcams. Have searched for Linux variants of this but with no luck. Anybody know of something similar for Ubuntu/Linux?

[image: Webcams thumbnail view]

Comment: "Webcams" own description could be helpful "The images don’t have to be produced by web cams. You can monitor any image which is updated over time like weather radars, traffic maps and so on."